# Automatic money send-OUT with PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Could not find on the web what I'm looking for.
I need to send mutliple payments to PayPal users with my PHP application. Payments might get sent at any time and they might be sent potentially to hundreds or thousands of users. I cannot find any way to do this automatically. Is there some PayPal API and a PHP class for this?
I see all Adaptive Payments variations allow only several receivers max. I need an unlimited amount of receivers!
Any hints, especially links to tutorials will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess the normal way to do this is to simply make one payment after another? You'll need a separate transaction ID for each payment anyway

Comment: my question is, how to do this specifically?

Comment: Send a separate payment to each recipient in a loop? I'm not sure what you want to know.

Comment: how to send the actual payment!

Comment: There's so much out there when Googling `php send money paypal`: e.g. [Paypal transfer money from one account to another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6117985) or [How to send money to paypal using php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4191887) does none of these results help?