# PayPal parallel payments

Tags: c#, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am developing a system that uses PayPal for processing payments. The users can buy and sell goods using their accounts on the system. I can process their deposits and purchases of their goods easily. However, when customers request withdrawal of credit from their balance, I want to be able to issue a PayPal parallel payment to all of those who requested it at the end of the month.

I've gone through the PayPal REST API and have found a lot of useful information on how to process payments of other users to my account, but I cannot seem to find an appropriate set of calls to enable me to issue several payments to several different users on my behalf (more precisely, from my own PayPal account).

This is a web application based on ASP.NET.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I don't need code examples (but could use them), references to appropriate documentation entries or similar implementation articles are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PayPal Mass Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/) seem to be the correct way to go with this.

I also found a related post that helped me decide: [Best way to pay a users paypal account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930264/best-way-to-pay-a-users-paypal-account).